# Is there a way to left-click links in gnome-terminal or am I out of luck?

Tags: gnome, command-line, mouse, gnome-terminal

I'm using `irssi` hosted on a remote computer for IRC, and it'd be super helpful not to have to hold Control or right-click every single link (so I can avoid multiple clicks or multiple hands).

At this point I'm willing to download `gnome-terminal`'s source and manually patch it and rebuild the package.

Comment: This is not a solution, but... it might be acceptable for you to map a button press to [ctrl]Left Click[/ctrl].

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be. If you really wanted that, then you would probably have to patch it as you said.

A helpful way of thinking about it is to open links sort of as a mouse gesture: Since Open Link is the first item on the right-click menu, a quick, small swipe to the bottom-right will open it with one click.

[image: Right click]
[image: Swipe and release]

There's some activity on this on these bugs, however:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-terminal/+bug/507109
- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=540023

Comment: The gesture thing would make sense if the menu always appeared at the same spot or in the same size. Thanks for the bug links, though. I think I might see if I can write a Terminator plugin to get what I want.

Comment: I ended up patching Terminator (a one-liner) for the behavior I wanted.